# What do parameterless constructors mean when explicitly called at declaration

Tags: c++

The question sounds a bit odd, but check the code sample

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b(), c("test");

    // No problems
    a = c;

    // tester.cpp:9:7: error: assignment of function ‘std::string b()’
    b = c;

    // tester.cpp:10:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::string (*)() {aka std::basic_string<char> (*)()}’ to ‘char’
    a = b;

    // No problems
    c = a;
}
```

You can see that it looks like b is created with the default constructor, but in fact it is not. So my question is really is, what does `string b()` mean?

Comment: Indeed almost a dupe, but I think worth answering due to the commas adding to the melee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condensing your code to `string b();`, what you're doing here is declaring a prototype to a *function* called `b` that returns a `string` and takes no arguments.

The commas in the "compound declaration" are obfuscating this.

Comment: Isn't calling it the "comma operator" a little misleading in itself? It's a list of declarators separated by commas, the comma operator is a different beast.

Comment: I think my terminology is correct; follows the C++ grammar.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Operators appear in expressions, not in declarator lists. This is indeed a declarator list.

Comment: e.g. `int i = 1, 2;` won't compile, the comma here is not an operator.

Comment: OK. I see your point. I've amended.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a function declaration. It's possible to declare local functions but not to define them. So therefore it's not possible to *explicitly* call the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Classic mistake, but the error message already says it: `function std::string b()` /.